# ggplot2: separate legend per layer

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot my data and got quite far with it (as I am a bloody beginner with R and ggplot). Now I'm stuck in making the legend:
I would like to have separate legend entries for line and point layers, which means something like
-- female
-- male
-- Plot A
-- Plot B
 O Start
 O End
 O Year 1

Any suggestions how to solve that problem?

```
test<-data.frame(id=1:6, sex=rep(c("female", "male"),times=3),   plot=rep(c("A", "B"), times=3), start=sample(seq(as.Date('2015/01/01'), as.Date('2016/01/01'), by="day"), 6), end=sample(seq(as.Date('2016/01/01'), as.Date('2016/10/01'), by="day"),6))  
test$duration <- difftime(test$end, test$start, units="days")  
test$Year1 <- as.Date(test$start+366)  
test$Year1[test$Year1>=Sys.Date() | test$duration<365] <-NA

startTime<- as.Date("2015-01-01")  
endTime <- Sys.Date()  
start.end <-c(startTime, endTime)

ggplot(test, aes(x=start, y=id, color=sex, linetype=plot))+             
      geom_segment(aes(x=start, xend=end, y=id, yend=id), size=.75)+          
      geom_point(aes(Year1), na.rm=TRUE, shape=16, size=3)+
      geom_point(aes(start), shape=1, size=3)+
  geom_point(data=subset(test, end!= Sys.Date()), aes(end), shape=13, size=3)+
      guides(color=guide_legend(title=NULL))+                                        
      scale_x_date(date_breaks="6 months", date_minor_breaks = "1 month", date_labels="%m/%Y", name="duration", limits=start.end)+  
      scale_color_discrete(name="", breaks=c("female", "male"), labels=c("f", "m"))+
      scale_linetype_manual(name="", breaks=c("A", "B"), labels=c("Plot A", "Plot B"), values=c("dotdash","solid"))+
      scale_shape_manual(name="", guide='legend', breaks=c("Year1", "start", "end"), labels=c("Year1", "start", "end"), values=c("16", "1", "13"))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtRy1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place the `start`, `end` and `Year1` in a common variable and map the `shape` aesthetic to this variable. This should work :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
test<-data.frame(id=1:6, sex=rep(c("female", "male"),times=3),   plot=rep(c("A", "B"), times=3), start=sample(seq(as.Date('2015/01/01'), as.Date('2016/01/01'), by="day"), 6), end=sample(seq(as.Date('2016/01/01'), as.Date('2016/10/01'), by="day"),6))  
test$duration <- difftime(test$end, test$start, units="days")  
test$Year1 <- as.Date(test$start+366)  
test$Year1[test$Year1>=Sys.Date() | test$duration<365] <-NA

startTime<- as.Date("2015-01-01")  
endTime <- Sys.Date()  
start.end <-c(startTime, endTime)

test_melt <- test %>% 
  select(id, sex, start, end, Year1) %>% 
  gather(type, value, -sex,-id)


ggplot(test)+             
  geom_segment(aes(x=start, xend=end, y=id, yend=id, color=sex, linetype=plot), size=.75)+          
  geom_point(aes(x = value, y = id, color = sex, shape = type), data = test_melt, size = 3) + 
  guides(color=guide_legend(title=NULL))+                                        
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="6 months", date_minor_breaks = "1 month", date_labels="%m/%Y", name="duration", limits=start.end)+  
  scale_color_discrete(name="", breaks=c("female", "male"), labels=c("f", "m"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(name="", breaks=c("A", "B"), labels=c("Plot A", "Plot B"), values=c("dotdash","solid"))+
  scale_shape_manual(name="", guide='legend', breaks=c("Year1", "start", "end"), labels=c("Year1", "start", "end"), values=c(16, 1, 13))
```

Comment: The shape numbers should not be quoted (e.g. 1 instead of 1)

Comment: Not sure how I lost the quotes, but: 1 instead of "1". Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked perfectly! :)
For now the only thing to solve is the legend for the sexes - it still has lines AND points, where it should have lines only...

Comment: After looking at this for a bit, I don't think you can do this easily. I submitted a [PR to ggplot2](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/pull/1760) to handle this, I'm waiting to hear back from it.